# DFA automaton that recognizes the following language

Tags: discrete-mathematics, automata

Need to construct a DFA automation that recognizes the following language of strings over the alphabet {a,b}:
The set of all strings that contain the pattern baa and end with b. (So, for example, your automaton should accept the string abaab and reject the string abaa.)  This is what i came up with but does not do the job completely I think or what?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your drawing, 'b' should go from '2' to '1', and 'a' from '4' to '3'. Then if the automaton ends on '4' you win and if it ends on '3' you lose.

Comment: How would you write this as regular expression. (a|b)+(baa)a*b  –